# Convert Angle to Velocity

Tags: physics, velocity, angle

How can I take an angle `dir` and convert it into a velocity `pos` where `pos` is a vector with x and y. For example, if `dir=90` then `pos=(1, 0)` because it is moving to the right. I know this is not the best explanation but if there is a better way to do this then please let me know. I'm trying to make a top-down car racing game.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180874/convert-angle-radians-to-a-heading-vector by [user61133](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61133/user61133)

> If you have an angle (A), in radians, in the range -Pi to Pi, then convert it to a vector (V) with:
>
> ```
> V.x = cos(A)
> V.y = sin(A)
> ```
>
> The inverse is `A = atan2(V.y, V.x)`

we can translate this into a simple calculation. below is the example in javascript, but it's equally easy to translate into other languages, as most of them provide Mathematical libraries.

What you then also need to account for is a method to convert from degrees to radians, like you can find at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#converting_between_degrees_and_radians

> Since humans tend to think in degrees, and some functions (such as CSS transforms) can accept degrees, it is a good idea to keep functions handy that convert between the two:
>
> ```
> function degToRad(degrees) {
>   return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
> };
> ```

So all this knowledge combined you can make a structure similar like this in the programming language of your choice.

```js
class Vector 
{
  constructor(X, Y) 
  {
     this.x = X;
     this.y = Y;
  }
  static fromRadian(radian, precision) 
  {
     let x = Math.cos(radian);
     let y = Math.sin(radian);
     if(!precision) {
      return new this(x,y);
     }
     return new this(x.toFixed(precision), y.toFixed(precision));
  }
  static fromAngle(angle, precision) 
  {
     return this.fromRadian(angle * (Math.PI/180), precision);
  }
}

const PRECISION = 3;

console.log(0, Vector.fromAngle(0, PRECISION));
console.log(45, Vector.fromAngle(45, PRECISION));
console.log(90, Vector.fromAngle(90, PRECISION));
console.log(135,Vector.fromAngle(135, PRECISION));
console.log(180, Vector.fromAngle(180, PRECISION));
console.log(225, Vector.fromAngle(225, PRECISION));
console.log(270, Vector.fromAngle(270, PRECISION));
console.log(315, Vector.fromAngle(315, PRECISION));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `pos = Vector(cos(radians(dir)), sin(radians(dir)))`